# Eloquent cannot find Code Igniter Model

Tags: codeigniter, laravel, eloquent

So I am using Eloquent with code igniter and getting some interesting bugs.

```
class Brand_model extends MY_Model {


public function size()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Size');
}
}
```

That line errors when trying to load my Size model:

```
class Size extends  MY_Model {

    public function brand(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Brand');

    }


}
```

"Unable to find class Size"

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you loading the class either through autoload or somewhere within your code?

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding autoload part, to your composer.json file, like here: http://snipr.it/~Dh

Then tun php composer.phar dumpautoload, it will load models from specified directories

After this, classes should be found.

Other option is just do $this->load->model('Brand_model'); $this->load->model('size');

Try both, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you loaded the composer autoload in your index file.

Please check out the full sample at [CodeIgniter_with_Eloquent](https://github.com/intuititve/codeigniter_eloquent)

Insert the code below right before the last line in your **index.php**:

```
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: @AliSajid sorry man.. I have removed this repo a couple weeks ago, there was no downloads on that and really I did not remember I had that posted here. I migrated everthing to Laravel...  I will try to find a backup on that but it´s not that hard to recreate that any way... just use the eloquent from laravel package itself. it has evolved a lot since 2015. I will remove this answer in a few weeks too.